# How to I configure htaccess - if file is not found at root search a subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

What do I put in htaccess so that if a file is not found at root, go look for it in a subfolder? I would like for my customers to be able type in this url:
**https://mysite/CustomerX.php**? but it resolve to 
**https://mysite/LandingPages/CustomerX.php**?

I don't want to redirect EVERYTHING away from root, only the files that aren't found there.

I have 600 customers, each with a custom landing page, so I need an automatic way for this to redirect. I do not actually want to put their 600 landing pages at the root so I am hoping for a way to redirect this. I'm pretty sure it's mod-rewrite but I can't figure out how to do the if-its-not-there part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/LandingPages/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /LandingPages/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava ! This is exactly what I needed and it worked exactly as requested. You rock!